# new fan has 3 wires, 1-white, 1-blue, 1-black. coming out of the ceil is 1-red, 1-white, and 1-black

Tags: wiring

Help: I can not understand how to connect these wires. my new fan has 1-white,1-blue,1-black. and from ceiling 1-red,1-white,1-black and 1-copper ground? The difference in matching the different colors makes no sense to me. I have tried many variations. Nothing works.

Comment: Because wiring is not color coded by application.  It is color coded by cable type.

Comment: I get that now, but that doesn't tell me how to hook up my fan.

Comment: How many wall switches control this fan?  1 or 2?

Comment: It's often that case that ground goes to ground, white goes to white, black goes to black, and other color except green (red, blue) goes to other color (green is typically ground).  However, you can't always count on the colors representing what you think they represent.  Wire runs to switches can use the colored wires in other ways, and non-electricians sometimes ignore the colors.  The only way to be sure is to use a meter to verify what wire is what.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the manual wiring diagram too? or if you don't have the manual the brand and model number of the fan.

Comment: Blue is usually the light kit, which is annoying. (blue = cold, IMO). Model number of fan, so I can look up what you should already have read?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how many switches control the fan, I assume you have 2 switches. 1 for the light and one for the fan. If this is the case, you hook black-black, white-white, bare(green)-bare(green), and red-blue. Then you should, if your house wiring is "normal", have the 2 switches controlling how they did before. Now, if you have 1 switch, then your red could be a traveler to another switch, a 3-way switch. In this case, the blue and black both go to black, white-white, bare(green)-bare(green), red to the other switch red(normally this would not have been unhooked if this is the case.)

Comment: It can't be travellers from a three-way; that would require more wires.  But it could be an always-hot and a switched-hot from the ceiling.